# Why would Oraclize fail when a normal post doesn't?

Tags: solidity, oracles, infura, external-api

I'm using the Oraclize test query to confirm my oraclize response is empty. [Here's a link](http://app.oraclize.it/home/test_query#VVJMKFBPU1Qp:anNvbihodHRwczovL21haW5uZXQuaW5mdXJhLmlvLykucmVzdWx0:eyJqc29ucnBjIjoiMi4wIiwiaWQiOjEsIm1ldGhvZCI6ImV0aF9ibG9ja051bWJlciIsInBhcmFtcyI6W119) to the exact test query, which contains the following:

```
URL  ["json(https://mainnet.infura.io/).result","{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[]}"]
_
```

When this same endpoint is queried with the same POST params from Postman like [here](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/2826444/infura/713fHG3) I get a correct response.

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,
  "result": "0x421283"
}
```

Why does Oraclize return an empty response instead?

Comment: for the record this is a test endpoint, I know you can access the current block number directly from solidity with `block.number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a reply from an Oraclize developer on their github that can be seen [here](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/issues/16). He says when using the second parameter as a POST payload a whitespace needs to be included at the beginning or end of the JSON object. [Here](http://app.oraclize.it/home/test_query#VVJMKFBPU1Qp:anNvbihodHRwczovL21haW5uZXQuaW5mdXJhLmlvLykucmVzdWx0:IHsianNvbnJwYyI6IjIuMCIsImlkIjoxLCJtZXRob2QiOiJldGhfYmxvY2tOdW1iZXIiLCJwYXJhbXMiOltdfQ==) is his updated version of my query returning a correct result